# Vuetify Expandable Data Table: Expand row position

Tags: vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

I'am experimenting with the expandable data table in Vuetify: [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#expandable-rows)

We can use the `<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers }">` template to customize the expanded item.

I want to show a simple-table in the expandable slot for each row. Currently I have managed to include this, but the column for the simple-table is within the header columns of the data-table.

How can i make the simple-table use more than one column of the data-table?

**EDIT: Working codepen:** https://codepen.io/5less/pen/QWWvYEw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've added fixes to the above logic you are trying

Find the working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/yLLbZWo?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :single-expand="singleExpand"
      :expanded.sync="expanded"
      item-key="name"
      show-expand
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-toolbar-title>Expandable Table</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-switch v-model="singleExpand" label="Single expand" class="mt-2"></v-switch>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">

        <v-simple-table>
              <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Dessert (400g serving)</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Fat</th>
                    <th>Carbs</th>
                    <th>Protein</th>
                    <th>Iron</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="dessert in desserts" :key="dessert.name">
                    <td>{{ dessert.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dessert.calories * 4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dessert.fat * 4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dessert.carbs * 4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dessert.protein * 4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ '4%' }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </template>
            </v-simple-table>
          </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      singleExpand: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        { text: '', value: 'data-table-expand' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Implementing <td> with colspan equal to the length of headers, made the v-simple-table use the columns it needed.